# Can't get ComboBox to update/refresh

Tags: c#, combobox, refresh

I have 2 forms, which I'll call Form1 and Form2. In Form1 is the following code:

```
public void PrinterDD()
{
    printer.Items.Clear();
    string sprinters = @"filepath";
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sprinters))
        try
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string strPrnItem = reader.ReadLine();
                MessageBox.Show(strPrnItem); //just here for troubleshooting purposes
                printer.Items.Add(strPrnItem);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
            printer.Update();
            printer.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
}
```

This method is called first when Form1 loads. The combobox ("printer") is populated correctly.

In Form2, I have a method to write to the file and change it:

```
private void accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AcceptButton = accept;
    if (selectedprinters != null && selectedprinters.Items != null && selectedprinters.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        File.Delete(sprinters);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sprinters);
        try
        {
            foreach (object item in selectedprinters.Items)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.Close();
            Voicemails.PrinterDD();
        }                
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

The line `Voicemails.PrinterDD();` runs the method from Form1 above. When stepping through the code, everything seems to work fine; no errors, the text file does get written with the new values. But the combobox never actually updates/refreshes to show the new strings.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT. I have tried `printer.Refresh();` instead of `printer.Update();` in the Form1 code.

ps. The file I'm using is a text file, so I don't think I'm able to bind the combobox to it, so I don't think doing `printer.DataSource = null` and then rebinding it would work.

Comment: Please don't prefix your question titles with "C#". That's what the tags are for?

Comment: What is the `Voicemails` object? Is it an instance of `Form1`?

Comment: Sorry. Voicemails is the actual class name of Form1. I just said Form1 for simplicity's sake

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to call the [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method

```
printer.Refresh();
```

You might look at using DataBinding to fill your combo box:

```
List<string> source = new List<string>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    source.Add(reader.ReadLine());

printer.DataSource = source;
printer.Refresh();
```

Comment: Sorry, I knew I'd miss something important. I've already tried printer.Refresh(); in place of the printer.Update(); that's in the code above. Unless I need to use both Refresh and Update for some reason.

I'll look into the data sourcing, but if I'm able to get this working...

Comment: So I tried data sourcing it. Even with a "printer.DataSource=null" at the beginning of the method followed by a "printer.DataSource=source" at the end, the combobox never updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the start of the PrinterDD() method.

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
   BeginInvoke(new NoParamDelegate(PrinterDD));
   return;
}
```

and add:

```
delegate void NoParamDelegate();
```

as a private property.

Comment: Tried this button didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Did you try adding the "Application.DoEvents()" method into the "PrinterDD" method at the end.  Also, I'm not sure I was clear on the InvokeRequired bit.  This needs to be in it's entirity at the start of the method, nothing else in the if statement, and all your existing code afterwards.